# How do I use a variable in a regular expression in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I've found a similar question and the answer in it didn't turn out to be working for me.
I want to do something like:

```
ItemModel.find({name: \^VARIABLEHERE\i});
```

doing a case insensitive search that finds anything that matches the variable.
Also I tried to do something on my own by using:

```
new RegExp(`/^${variablehere}/`, 'i')
```

And

```
new RegExp(`/^${variablehere}/i`)
```

Yeah I'm new to regular expressions.

All help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `$regex` [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#examples)

Comment: @Drunk : What has not worked ? Can you give us few sample docs & required o/p & also what you're seeing now..

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, this question is about mongoose, not mongodb in particular. Syntax is not exactly same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$regex`

```
ItemModel.find({
    name: {
        $regex: '.*' + name + '.*', //or you can use `.*${name}.*`
        $options: 'i'
    }   
});
```

There is a complete manual for variety of regular expression at [mongodb $regex manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#examples)